# Help combining two BTRFS filesystems converted from ext4

Tags: mount, btrfs

So, I have three hard drives in my computer, and am running Ubuntu 22.04.1
`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdc1` are two internal drives that were originally `EXT4`, but converted to `btrfs` successfully with no issues. `/dev/sda1` was originally mounted at `/nasa/16TB`, while `/dev/sdc1` was mounted at `/nasa/14TB`. `/dev/sdb3` is the root drive and should remain as `EXT4`

Here's what I did.

1. I rebooted into rescue mode by running `systemctl rescue`
2. I converted both hard drives by running the following commands:

`for id in sda1 sdc1;do fsck.ext4 -fyv /dev/$id;btrfs-convert -d -p -L /dev/$id;done`

3. After that completed, I modified `/etc/fstab` to add this line, also
   removing the old entries for the mount points.

`UUID=(id of /dev/sdc1) /nasa btrfs compress=zstd:8,noatime 0 0`

4. I made a subdirectory in `/nasa` called `14TB` and moved everything
   at the root level into that subdirectory.
5. I repeated steps 3 and 4 with `/dev/sda1`, except named the
   subdirectory `16TB`.

Now, I tried to run the following command to attempt to combine everything as if it were a raid.

```
btrfs device add /dev/sda1 /nasa
```

Instead, I get this error message.

```
/dev/sda1 appears to contain an existing filesystem (btrfs).
ERROR: use the -f option to force overwrite of /dev/sda1
```

How can I combine both drives without overwriting the data on either drive? I also want it to be running in single mode for data and dup for metadata.

Comment: You can't add a device preserving data on it. It is very unclear what you did.

Comment: It doesn't matter that fs has been converted from ext4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another disk to an existing `btrfs` filesystem, you need to backup existing data from the disk you want to add. It will be cleared.

Then you'll be able to add the device. After that you can restore the data.

It doesn't matter where you mount the disks currently.

After that you'll have one `btrfs` filesystem that can be mounted to one place by any of the disks.